# How long does Android BillingClient store results offline, for onQueryPurchasesResponse?

Tags: android, billingclient

I am currently testing my integration of BillingClient.

One of the tests is to close all internet connections of the mobile phone.
I did expect that this will create a call to onBillingServiceDisconnected().
But it doesnt.  So clearly there is no internet connection, and it is impossible
for BillingClient to connect to Google Servers. But ... when calling
mBillingClient.queryPurchasesAsync() i do get a callback to onQueryPurchasesResponse(). The List of purchases is -good-.
Obviously Google cached this locally from previous calls when the Internet was on. I love that ! Great job.
I just dont know how reliable that is. This is not specified. Can i rely on this ? How long will it store ?  I have different products (subscriptions), with variable length (week, month).  Is the caching code good enough to make its own guess (= will it handle weekly subscriptions differently from monthly ones ?).

I thought i would have to handle this myself, and had code prepared to
do plausibility checks, using timestamps. Has anybody any experience with this ? This is V5 of BillingClient.